# how to read a string using multiple delimiters in matlab

Tags: string, matlab

I use Matlab to process a huge file with complicated and not standard format. That's why I chose to use the strread command. Now, I want to split further a string variable, taken from the input file. E.g.:

```
str='DIDYMO-OREST.1;DIDYMOTE.150.L150;1;LINE'
[dev nod conn equip]= strread(str,'%s %s %d %s','delimiter',';');
```

The nod variable is:

```
nod = 'DIDYMOTE.150.L150'
```

How can I split this variable using a dot ('.') as delimiter ?

Answer (score 1):

```
result = regexp(nod,'\.','split');
```

This gives a cell array of strings. In your example,

```
>> result{:}

ans = 

    'DIDYMOTE'    '150'    'L150'
```

Comment: Note that if you want to split on multiple delimiters, as the title suggests, simply change the regexp line to something like `regexp(str,[;|.|-]','Split')` where the second argument contains all necessary delimiters separated by a `|`

Comment: And don't forget to escape delimiters like `.`, which have a special meaning in `regexp` (that is, write them as `\.`)

Comment: MATLAB did not seem to really care when I tested it but it is good practice in to do this anyway. Good call